# MySQL / PDO - Select from other table (Join statement)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, left-join, inner-join

I have a PDO statement, that selects some data from some different tables. Although, I am unsure on how I can select data from yet another table:

```
SELECT 
        c.forum_id as category_id,
        c.forum_name as category_name,
        t.forum_id as id,
        t.forum_name as name,
        t.forum_desc as description,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND topic_deleted=0) as topics_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND post_deleted=0) as posts_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=lp.topic_id AND post_deleted=0) as last_post_count,
        lp.topic_id as last_post_topic_id,
        lp.topic_title as last_post_topic_title,
        lp.post_time as last_post_time,
        lp.username as last_post_username
    FROM forum_cats as t
    JOIN forum_cats as c on c.forum_id = t.forum_type_id
    left join (
        SELECT 
            ft.topic_id,
            ft.title as topic_title,
            tmp.post_time,
            u.username,
            fp.forum_id
        FROM
            forum_posts fp
            join forum_topics ft on ft.topic_id = fp.topic_id
            join users u on u.id = fp.userid
            join (
                select forum_id, max(`post_time`) `post_time`
                from forum_posts fp
                where fp.post_deleted = 0
                group by forum_id
                ) as tmp on (fp.forum_id = tmp.forum_id and fp.post_time = tmp.post_time)
        where post_deleted = 0 and ft.topic_deleted = 0
    ) as lp on lp.forum_id = t.forum_id
    where t.forum_active = 1 and c.forum_active = 1
    order by category_id, t.forum_id
");
```

Now, I want to select the column `avatar`.`users` where `username`.`users` is = `last_post_username` (`avatar` column, from the `users` table).

I have absolute no idea on where to start. Should I put it something like this?

```
(SELECT avatar FROM users WHERE username=last_post_username)
```

That doesn't work though.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have "last_post_username" based on a join as "u.id = fp.userid". You just need to retrieve "lp.avatar"

Here is my answer :

```
SELECT 
        c.forum_id as category_id,
        c.forum_name as category_name,
        t.forum_id as id,
        t.forum_name as name,
        t.forum_desc as description,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_topics WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND topic_deleted=0) as topics_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE forum_id=t.forum_id AND post_deleted=0) as posts_count,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id=lp.topic_id AND post_deleted=0) as last_post_count,
        lp.topic_id as last_post_topic_id,
        lp.topic_title as last_post_topic_title,
        lp.post_time as last_post_time,
        lp.username as last_post_username,
        lp.avatar
    FROM forum_cats as t
    JOIN forum_cats as c on c.forum_id = t.forum_type_id
    left join (
        SELECT 
            ft.topic_id,
            ft.title as topic_title,
            tmp.post_time,
            u.username,
            u.avatar,
            fp.forum_id
        FROM
            forum_posts fp
            join forum_topics ft on ft.topic_id = fp.topic_id
            join users u on u.id = fp.userid
            join (
                select forum_id, max(`post_time`) `post_time`
                from forum_posts fp
                where fp.post_deleted = 0
                group by forum_id
                ) as tmp on (fp.forum_id = tmp.forum_id and fp.post_time = tmp.post_time)
        where post_deleted = 0 and ft.topic_deleted = 0
    ) as lp on lp.forum_id = t.forum_id
    where t.forum_active = 1 and c.forum_active = 1
    order by category_id, t.forum_id
");
```

Comment: How will I then be able to use "avatar" with php? $row['avatar']?